# Ocupo consumir un api

Tags: nodejs, angular

Buenas amigos estoy iniciando en este mundo, y ocupo la ayuda de uds necesito que me muestre del API de RAWG los géneros pero los géneros estén así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que logro hacer es que me muestre todos los géneros pero ocupo solamente hacer que me muestre lo del paréntesis {}0

o sea, solo lo del genero de acción que como se ve en la imagen sería GTA V, The Witcher, entre otros

pero no logro hacer que me muestre solo lo de ese paréntesis {}0

todo esto lo estoy trabajando en Angular y en visual estudio

Les agradecería de corazón toda la ayuda que me pueda brindar, de ante mano muchas gracias!!!!!

esto es parte del código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me muestra esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que ocupo es que me muestre lo que esta dentro por poner un ejemplo del genero de acción

Comment: Esto es parte del codigo

Comment: Es "necesito" en lugar de "ocupo".

Comment: @Lobos en otras partes de latinoamérica, ocupar es sinónimo de necesitar ;) Ocupas pasarte por México, parce

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: @Lobos, a mi también me suena "mal", pero al parecer es un *Americanismo* de la lengua española presente en algunos países de centroamérica y en Chile. [La RAE dice que se puede considerar "vulgar" en otras zonas donde no se usa con esta acepción.](https://www.rae.es/duda-linguistica/es-valido-el-uso-de-ocupar-con-el-significado-de-necesitar), pero tiene una acepción a "necesitar" según el [diccionario de americanismos](https://www.asale.org/damer/ocupar).

Answer (score 6):

Solo te hizo falta hacer un pipe y map en el servicio para obtener los resultados, agrego código:

**game.service.ts**

```
export class GameService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  private readonly token: string = 'AQUI_VA_TU_T';
  private readonly apiUrl: string = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/';

  getGenres(): Observable<Genre[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Result>(`${this.apiUrl}genres?&key=${this.token}`)
      .pipe(
        map(({ results }) => results),
        catchError(() => of([]))
      );
  }
  getGamesByGenre(genre: string): Observable<Game[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<GamesByGenre>(
        `${this.apiUrl}games?&genres=${genre}&key=${this.token}`
      )
      .pipe(
        map(({ results }) => results),
        catchError(() => of([]))
      );
  }
}
```

**genre-page-component.ts**

```
export class GenrePageComponent implements OnInit {

  genres: Genre[] = [];

  constructor(private gameService: GameService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gameService.getGenres().subscribe((genres) => (this.genres = genres));
  }
}
```

**action-page-component.ts**

```
export class ActionPageComponent implements OnInit {
  games: Game[] = [];

  constructor(private gameService: GameService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gameService
      .getGamesByGenre('action')
      .subscribe((games) => (this.games = games));
  }
}
```

**game.interface.ts**

```
export interface Result {
  count: number;
  next: null;
  previous: null;
  results: Genre[];
}

export interface Genre {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  slug: string;
  games_count: number;
  image_background: string;
  games: GameElement[];
}

export interface GameElement {
  id: number;
  slug: string;
  name: string;
  added: number;
}

export interface GamesByGenre {
  count: number;
  next: string;
  previous: null;
  results: Result[];
  user_platforms: boolean;
}

export interface Game {
  slug: string;
  name: string;
  playtime: number;
  platforms: Platform[];
  stores: Store[];
  released: Date;
  tba: boolean;
  background_image: string;
  rating: number;
  rating_top: number;
  ratings: Rating[];
  ratings_count: number;
  reviews_text_count: number;
  added: number;
  added_by_status: AddedByStatus;
  metacritic: number;
  suggestions_count: number;
  updated: Date;
  id: number;
  score: null;
  clip: null;
  tags: Tag[];
  esrb_rating: EsrbRating;
  user_game: null;
  reviews_count: number;
  saturated_color: Color;
  dominant_color: Color;
  short_screenshots: ShortScreenshot[];
  parent_platforms: Platform[];
  genres: Genre[];
}
```

Para obtener las interfaces copia la respuesta que recibes al momento de hacer la petición GET en [Quicktype.io](https://quicktype.io/) para que puedas tenerlas de forma más fácil, hay varias que no agregué por cuestiones de no hacer esto mas largo.

Resultados:
[image]
[image]

Te aconsejo guardar los géneros y tal vez los juegos de cada género en el localStorage para evitar hacer tantas peticiones. Necesitarías lo siguiente:

```
generos: Genre[] = [];
```

En el gameService dentro de la petición puedes agregar:

```
localStorage.setItem('generos', JSON.stringify(this.generos));
```

y dentro del constructor, pero esta vez para leerlos:

```
this.generos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('generos')!) || [];
```

Comment: No había visto la actualización que pusiste, asī que supongo que solamente tienes problemas para sacar los datos del JSON.

Comment: si correcto, no se como hacer para sacar los datos del json, lo que necesito seria mostrar los juegos del genero accion, en un apartado los de indie en otro y asi consecutivamente

Comment: Entendí que querías que te mostrará cada género con sus datos, pero parece que quieres que te muestre los juegos de cada género? Las capturas de pantalla están algo confusas y no tienes tipos de datos, al usar el tipo any para todo básicamente evitas una de las mayores ventajas de TypeScript que es el checado de tipados y cuando recibas algo que no es lo que quieres recibir te va a tronar todo.

Comment: De igual forma ya añadí el código para que muestre los juegos también, si te das cuenta es el mismo pero con diferentes urls.